# A word for something that is antiquated but still in use

Tags: phrases, verbs

This word can be used in the following scenarios

- Old laws that would seem funny if passed today, are still in use today.
- A form of speech spoken that would sound Shakespearean today.
- Holdover from a time before now.

Comment: Do you mean ***outdated***?

Comment: Perhaps [*old-fashioned*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/old-fashioned).

Comment: If you are asking for a "SWR", could you please add a sample sentence of how you would like the word to be used? This is more or less required on this forum.

Comment: Merriam-Webster offers as one definition of **superannuated** "outmoded, old-fashioned"—which may be what you have in mind here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Anachronism**

> a person or a thing that is chronologically out of place; especially :  one from a former age that is incongruous in the present

"Anachronism." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 3 Jan. 2017.

Comment: Worth noting that anachronism works the other way around.  When you are watching a movie about medieval knights and catch a glimpse of an actor's digital watch under his sleeve, that would also be deemed an anachronism.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Archaic
>
> **Adjective**
>   2. (of a linguistic form) commonly used in an earlier time but rare in present-day usage except to suggest the older time, as in religious rituals or historical novels.
>   Examples:
>   *thou; wast; methinks; forsooth.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/archaic))

Just as the question asks for, Shakespearean words like *thou* and *forsooth* fall neatly into this definition.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd say you're pretty much spot on with **"antiquated"** already - it fits the bill for the examples you posted.

You could use the roughly synonymous:

[**Archaic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/archaic):

- *Very old or old-fashioned*
- *(of a word or a style of language) no longer in everyday use but sometimes used to impart an old-fashioned flavour*

[**Archaism**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/archaism):

- *A thing that is very old or old-fashioned, especially an archaic word or style of language or art*

Could you also perhaps use the noun [**Relic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relic)?

*"An object surviving from an earlier time, especially one of historical interest"*

> The act of severing hands for the crime of theft is a 7th-century **relic**.

Comment: I like the sound of relic, but wouldn't it be applicable to tangible objects only?

Comment: @AdityaTalpade I agree - just added an update. I think Archaic/Archaism would be better for the more abstract.

Comment: @mattsch Great minds!

Answer (score 0):

I could think of the following additional options. The meanings of these words (given by Google) are also provided below -

**Persistent**: Continuing firmly or obstinately in an opinion or course of action in spite of difficulty or opposition

**Enduring**:   Lasting over a period of time; durable.

**Surviving**:  Continue to live or exist, especially in spite of danger or hardship.

Answer (score 0):

It is a ***legacy*** - something from the past which exists today only for that reason.

ODO:

> **[legacy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/legacy)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1** Something left or handed down by a predecessor
>
> ‘The real issue here is not public dental services, but flawed
>   national health policy, and its legacy.’